# LUN's WWN as PK in a table

Tags: database, san

I am developing an application to monitor RAIDs and LUNs. As part of that, I've to design a table that keeps LUN information of RAIDs from various vendors. I know there is a standard in vendor-specific WWN but I am not so sure how unique that WWN is across RAIDs. Say, if a HP EVA LUN  has WWN of 6001438009B013EC0000700000050000 then how safe it is to assume no RAID ever will have this WWN for one of their LUNs? I want WWN as PK of my 'lun info' table. Is that alright?

Kindly assist me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A WWN should be a Globally unique Identifier from any vendor that has its own IEEE OUI Number.

http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/oui.txt